# phaser - container not moving it's objects

Tags: phaser-framework, phaserjs

I'm using external class with a container and trying to move it

```
import Phaser from 'phaser';

export default class tabContainer extends Phaser.GameObjects.Container {

  container_hit_clicker;

  constructor(scene){
    super(scene);

    this.container_hit_clicker = this.scene.add.rectangle(this.scene.scale.width-100, this.scene.scale.height-100, 50, 100, 0xff0000).setOrigin(0).setDepth(8);
    this.container_hit_clicker.setInteractive().on('pointerdown', () => {
      this.openContainer();
    });

  }

  openContainer(){
    this.scene.tweens.add({
      targets  :this,
      x        :{from:this.x, to:100},
      ease     :'Cubic.easeOut',
      duration :500,
      onUpdate :function(){ console.log(this.x); }
    });
  }

}
```

So I add this container to my scene

```
this.tabContainer = new tabContainer(this);
```

Container is being added fine with it's objects but the tween is not working.

I can see position X is being changed in `console.log` but the objects keeps in same position.

Am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you need to add, the ***gameobject*** to the ***container***, and the ***container*** to the ***scene***, so that it works.

In your current code you are just adding the ***rectangle*** to the ***scene***.

**Here is a small Demo:**

```js
document.body.style = 'margin:0;';

class tabContainer extends Phaser.GameObjects.Container {

  container_hit_clicker;

  constructor(scene){
    super(scene);

    this.container_hit_clicker = this.scene.add.rectangle( 50, 50, 50, 80, 0xff0000)
        .setOrigin(0)
        .setDepth(8);
    this.container_hit_clicker
        .setInteractive()
        .on('pointerdown', () => {
            this.openContainer();
        });
    this.add(this.container_hit_clicker);
  }

  openContainer(){
    this.scene.tweens.add({
      targets  : this,
      x        : { from: this.x, to: 200 },
      ease     : 'Cubic.easeOut',
      duration : 500,
      onUpdate : () => { console.log(this.x); },
    });
  }
}

var config = {
    type: Phaser.AUTO,
    width: 536,
    height: 183,
    scene: { create },
}; 

function create () {
    this.add.text(10,10, 'Click the Red-Rectangle')
        .setScale(1.5)
        .setOrigin(0)
        .setStyle({fontStyle: 'bold', fontFamily: 'Arial'});

    let container = new tabContainer(this);
    
    this.add.existing(container);
}

new Phaser.Game(config);
console.clear()
```

```html
<script src="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/phaser/dist/phaser.min.js"></script>
```